# Accessing embedded JSON using decodable in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, urlsession, decodable

I am trying to access a particular an embedded array of dictionaries to create my swift objects. I am unsure about how to access that array in the JSON dictionary.

Here is the definition of my Swift object = StarWarsPeople

```
class StarWarsPeople: Decodable {

    var name: String?
    var height: String?
    var weight: String?
    var hair_color: String?
    var skin_color: String?
    var eye_color: String?
    var birth_year: String?
    var gender: String?
}
```

Here is my APIClient class:

```
class StarWarsPeopleAPIClient
{
    class func getStarWarsPeopleInformation (page: Int, completion:@escaping ([StarWarsPeople])-> ()) throws {

        let starWarsPeopleURL = "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=\(page)"

        let convertedStarWarsPeopleURL = URL(string: starWarsPeopleURL)

        guard let unwrappedConvertedStarWarsPeopleURL = convertedStarWarsPeopleURL else { print("unwrappedConvertedStarWarsPeopleURL did not unwrap"); return}

        let request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedConvertedStarWarsPeopleURL)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let unwrappedData = data else { print("unwrappedData did not unwrap"); return}

            do {
                let starWarsPeopleDataArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([StarWarsPeople].self, from: unwrappedData)

                completion(starWarsPeopleDataArray)
            }
            catch let error {
                print("Error occured here: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Here is my Json, it is the results array that I would like to access, it is an array of dictionaries, which I need to iterate over to create my StarWarsPeople Object.

```
{
    "count": 87,
    "next": "url",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker",
            "height": "172",
            "mass": "77",
            "hair_color": "blond",
            "skin_color": "fair",
            "eye_color": "blue",
            "birth_year": "19BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "url",
            "films": [
                "url",
                "url",
                "url",
                "url",
                "url"
            ],
            "species": [
                "url"
            ],
            "vehicles": [
                "url",
                "url"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define a wrapper struct that holds the `results` property from the JSON response.

```
struct ApiResponse: Decodable {
  results: [StarWarsPeople]
}
```

and later use

```
let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
let starWarsPeopleDataArray = apiResponse.results
```

to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the JSON. You are ignoring the enclosing object

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let count: Int
    let next: URL?
    let previous: URL?
    let results : [StarWarsPeople]
}


struct StarWarsPeople: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { 
        case name, height, mass
        case hairColor = "hair_color", skinColor = "skin_color"
        case eyeColor = "eye_color", birthYear = "birth_year", gender
    }

    let name: String
    let height: String
    let mass: String
    let hairColor: String
    let skinColor: String
    let eyeColor: String
    let birthYear: String
    let gender: String
}
```

---

```
...
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: unwrappedData)
let starWarsPeopleDataArray = root.results
...
```

---

Notes:

- A struct is sufficient.
- Map the *snake_cased* keys to *camelCased* properties.
- In almost all cases the properties can be declared as constants (`let`).
- Don't declare all properties schematically as optional. Declare only those as optional which corresponding key can be missing or the value can be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Results you are trying to fetch is actually present in `results` keys. Also we need to use properties same as parameter name( we can use CodingKeys enum too for overriding this).

> So, first parse outer JSON , In new struct say `StarWarsPeopleParent`

```
class StarWarsPeopleParent: Decodable {
    var count: Int?
    var results: [StarWarsPeople]?
}
```

> Update your `StarWarsPeople` struct's properties as:

```
class StarWarsPeople: Decodable {

    var name: String?
    var height: String?
    var mass: String?
    var hair_color: String?
    var skin_color: String?
    var eye_color: String?
    var birth_year: String?
    var gender: String?
}
```

> Then parse it like:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let unwrappedData = data else { print("unwrappedData did not unwrap"); return}

        do {
            let starWarsPeopleDataArray = try JSONDecoder().decode(StarWarsPeopleParent.self, from: unwrappedData)

            completion(starWarsPeopleDataArray)
        }
        catch let error {
            print("Error occured here: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Hope this is fine for you to understand.